# detect the application that sent sms in android

Tags: android, sms

I'm new to android Develpoment
my first application is ant-spy
I try to detect the application that sent sms (that is listening to send an sms )
I ask you to help me this application and if possible give me a source code for DECT application waiting to send sms or a code that resemble.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code is used to send sms:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumberToSend, null, smsTextToSend, null, null);
```

Comment: I like that you try to help me, but I do not want to send sms, I look for how the application Decter who want to send an sms (detect the spy who send sms without knowledge of the user).